# Require Commit Message With Subclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, centos, subclipse

How do I force a commit message (message that is not null) using the Eclipse addon Subclipse?

The repositories that I am using are on a CentOS 6.5 Linux server, using SVN 1.6.11.

I've been trying to modify the repo's pre-commit.tmpl directly from the server, and have copied code posted from other stackoverflow  answers, but none seem to work when I make a commit in Eclipse.

I don't want to setup a template, but want the user making the commit to enter in what is being changed. I know in a previous question people stated that this won't solve the "commit culture" that we have, but  I still need to force the not null commit.

Thanks!

Comment: The `pre-commit.tmpl` is an example file.  You should copy it to a file called simply `pre-commit` and make sure that it is executable.

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  I've made my comment into an answer, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre-commit.tmpl` is an example file. You should copy it to a file called simply `pre-commit` and make sure that it is executable.